# How to include custom directive to another custom directive's template(html) in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I hava a directive already(appView) and that has some html to load through templateUrl. As of now, I need to add one more custom directive to the template that is being used by another directive(appView).

Please see my code below and it is not working as expected. Any help on this how i can make this work please?

View.html (template)

```
<div>
    <div class="dragdrop" id="dropzone" dropzone> //here is my custom directive
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>UPLOAD ASSETS</span>
        <input id="dzFile" type="file" class="upload" />
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

angular js

```
var appModule = angular.module("Newapp", []);

appModule.directive("appView", appView);
function appView(){
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/View.html'
    };
    return directive;
}

appModule.directive("dropzone", function(){  //This is added to the View.html as attribute(see above html code with **)
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: FullDragDrop
    };
    return directive;
});

function FullDragDrop(){
    console.log("soemthing goes here");
}
```

How can I make this possible Please?

Comment: why ** dropzone ** instead of  dropzone inside your View.html ?

Comment: @NicolasHumbert, That is to notify whoever refer, thats it. it is only dropzone

Comment: @User123 What are you looking for? Your code is working. You can check out the plunker and see. The text 'something goes here' is shown.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vwIrM7D402juEDDHDKbC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. 
Make sure **templateUrl: 'app/View.html'** exists

```
<script>

var appModule = angular.module("Newapp", []);

    appModule.directive("appView", appView);

        function appView(){

            var directive = {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'view.html'
            };

            return directive;

      }



    appModule.directive("dropzone", function(){  //This is added to the View.html as attribute(see above html code with **)


         var directive = {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: FullDragDrop
            };

            return directive;

    });




    function FullDragDrop(){

        console.log("soemthing goes here");

    }


</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="view.html">
   <div class="dragdrop" id="dropzone" dropzone> //here is my custom directive
          <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
          <span>UPLOAD ASSETS</span>
          <input id="dzFile" type="file" class="upload" />
          </div> 
      </div>
</script>

<body>
  <app-view></app-view>
</body>
```